# How to download 300 dpi image of a styled google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to download a 300 dpi image of a styled google map for printing purposes. I know i can already download 300 dpi image of a basic map via google my maps. But i want to download 300 dpi image of this map: https://snazzymaps.com/style/122/flat-map-with-labels (or any other styled map)

Is there any way? I will try doing a styled map via my own website but even then, how will i download a printable version of it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Google Maps [Static Maps API V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/intro) to download a map. Look at the [styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/intro#StyledMaps) section for more information on styling.  
[This](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=512x512&zoom=15&center=Brooklyn&style=feature:road.local%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x00ff00%7Cweight:1%7Cvisibility:on&style=feature:landscape%7Celement:geometry.fill%7Ccolor:0x000000%7Cvisibility:on&style=feature:administrative%7Celement:labels%7Cweight:3.9%7Cvisibility:on%7Cinverse_lightness:true&style=feature:poi%7Cvisibility:simplified) is the example given in the documentation.

using it for free limit your image size to 640x640, you can apply for Google Maps API for Work to gain access to 2048x2048 image size.